# What does gets.chomp do?

Tags: ruby

I was also wondering if I always have to put the exclamation point after .capitalize!

```
print "What's your first name? "
first_name = gets.chomp
first_name.capitalize!

print "What's your last name? "
last_name = gets.chomp
last_name.capitalize!

print "What city are you from? "
city = gets.chomp
city.capitalize!

print "What state or province are you from? "
state = gets.chomp
state.capitalize!.upcase!


puts "Your name is #{first_name} #{last_name} and you're from #{city}, #{state}!"
```

Comment: Use `puts` instead of `print`.

Comment: Note `!` is not an operator but a part of the method name. `method` and `method!` are completely different methods.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could explain which *exact* parts of the documentation of `Kernel#gets`, `String#chomp`, `String#capitalize`, and `String#capitalize!` are unclear to you. That way, the Ruby community can improve the documentation so that questions like this don't arise again.

Answer (score 4):

> What does gets.chomp do?

If you type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>return</kbd> then [`gets`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) would return `"denis\n"` where `\n` is the line feed character from the <kbd>return</kbd> key. [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes such trailing [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

```
"denis\n".chomp
#=> "denis"
```

> I was also wondering if I always have to put the exclamation point after .capitalize!

In general, a bang method is a method like any other: (from the documentation for [method names](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/doc/syntax/methods_rdoc.html#label-Method+Names))

> The bang methods (`!` at the end of method name) are called and executed just like any other method.

But:

> [...] by convention, a method with an exclamation point or bang is considered dangerous.

*Dangerous* can mean various things, depending on the context. For built-in methods from Ruby's core library it usually means:

> [...] that when a method ends with a bang (`!`), it indicates that unlike its non-bang equivalent, permanently modifies its receiver.

So [`capitalize!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) (with `!`) will modify `first_name`: (the method's receiver)

```
first_name = 'denis'    #=> "denis"
first_name.capitalize!  #=> "Denis"
first_name              #=> "Denis"
```

`capitalize!` will also return `nil` if the string is already capitalized:

```
first_name = 'Denis'    #=> "Denis"
first_name.capitalize!  #=> nil
first_name              #=> "Denis"
```

Whereas [`capitalize`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/String.html#method-i-capitalize) (without `!`) will always return a new (capitalized) string, leaving `first_name` unchanged:

```
first_name = 'denis'    #=> "denis"
first_name.capitalize   #=> "Denis"
first_name              #=> "denis"
```

Apparently, the `capitalize` call above doesn't make much sense because the return value is not used anywhere. You usually want to do something with that new string like assigning it to a variable:

```
capitalized_first_name = first_name.capitalize
```

or passing it to a method:

```
puts "Your name is #{first_name.capitalize}"
```

Answer (score 0):

chomp removes the linebreak character at the end of the string input.
Adding the ! will mutate the value of your variable. It is not required. It depends on your use case.

```
foo = 'foo'
foo.capitalize
print foo
=> 'foo'

bar = 'bar'
bar.capitalize!
print bar
=> 'Bar'
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't need the "!". Let's try to get by without them:

```
print "What's your first name? "
first_name = gets.chomp.capitalize

print "What's your last name? "
last_name = gets.chomp.capitalize

print "What city are you from? "
city = gets.chomp.capitalize

print "What state or province are you from? "
state = gets.chomp.upcase

puts "Your name is #{first_name} #{last_name} and you're from #{city}, #{state}!"
```

There you go. You can avoid mutation and just manipulate your strings with standard methods. No "!" methods need apply!

ps: capitalize followed by upcase is the same as just upcase.

Comment: In what cases would you use the ( ! )? thanks didn't even realize we could do that.

Comment: It varies a lot, and the best answer is to study the documentation on each method of interest. My PickAxe book is well worn from being used so frequently to clear up questions about Ruby. Still, methods ending in "!" **often** but not always either modify data "in place" in a variable or do something that requires some caution.